# Add record to object wiith and check errors with platform event

Tags: batch, platform-event

I cannot find the information I need about this.
What i am trying:
Add some records to Account object with Batch and checking errors if Platoform Event.
So if records added i want to write in platform event "Succesfull"  and vice versa.
I just want to know how to do it. Some guides would be perfect.

UPD:
Or i must just use batch as always and catch error with try-catch and then write to   event?

Comment: You want to initiate a platform event regardless of the outcome (success or failure)? The developer guide for [Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm) is a good starting point.

Comment: @nbrown yeah. I read this, but didn't found, But i will look again, thanks.

Comment: Is [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm) what you're looking for? The benefit of this approach is that it handles both catchable exceptions and governor limit issues.

Comment: @PhilW I think it works for me, but i am trying to make it with my own event.

Comment: To handle governor limit issues you have to use this standard event.